# MongoDB query based on month and date

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

So, I have this data in my DB,

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "from": "1970-01-01",
    "to": "1970-01-05"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "from": "2017-04-18",
    "to": "2017-04-23"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "from": "2018-01-29",
    "to": "2018-01-30"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "from": "2018-01-02",
    "to": "2018-01-08"
  }
]
```

Is it possible that I pass year as **2018** and month as **01** then I get matching data from the all data? Like here I got last two Documents from collection.

I tried **$elemMatch:** query but didn't get expected result.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try below:

```
db.collection.find( 
    {"from": {"$gte": new Date(2018, 0, 1), "$lt": new Date(2018, 1, 1)}}
)
```

Also, do remember that that in the Date() function, the month argument starts counting at 0, not 1.

**Update:**
MongoDB V3.4

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {$project: {  "month" : {$month: '$date'}, "year" : {$year: '$date'}}},
      {$match: { month: 1, year: 2018}}
    ]);
```

Comment: should this be `"$lt": new Date(2018, 1, 1)` ?

Comment: Yes.. I will update the answer.. or it can be `"$lte"`

Comment: If you use `$lte` then you need to include the time for 23:59:59...rather use `$lt` and the next date.

Comment: I think you are correct. I have come across a new answer after you had suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex. Following example using mongoose :

```
model.find({
  from: {
     $regex: new RegExp('2018-01-', ''),
  },
});
```

Or

```
model.find({
  from: {
     $regex: /2018-01-/,
  },
});
```

---

Using mongoshell format :

```
db.collection.find({
  from: {
    $regex: "2018-01"
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/udRts-zp2D9

Comment: Can I use regex in mongoplayground? I'm getting error while using this regex